# Nice logos/symbols/pictures packages

Tags: fontawesome

I'm currently working on my resume, and I would like to present my hobbies with symbols.
I checked out the "The Comprehensive LATEX Symbol List", it's great, but I cant find everything I need.
For example, I'm looking for a badminton symbol or a movie symbol.

Do you have some recommandations ?

Comment: Have a look to https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome or https://www.ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome5

Comment: Google "badminton icon" and save your favorite image. Then import into your document with `\includegraphics`

Comment: @SandyG Of course but I want to know if I'm missing some really nice packages.

Comment: As you have found from the list included fontawsome the entry for movie `\faFilm` should be universally understood. However for sports other than soccer you could use a dedicated font admittedly it can be fiddly to include say just the Capital S from https://www.fontspace.com/kats-fun-fonts/kr-all-sport/9519/charmap I would tend to go with a www search for icons then use the easier include graphics

Comment: http://www.Iconfinder.com is a good source imo for vector based icons. However images are bit more of a hassle to apply. I think you can also try to search for 'dingbat fonts', available on the internet on several websites. Eg https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/list/classification/dingbat